# Should I use "turning to X" or "turning into X" in the following case?

Tags: word-choice

> The primary fuel of the human body is slowly turning **to/into** fast
>   food.

Should I use *to* or *into*? And why?

Comment: I wouldn't use *turning*, because that means the food itself is changing. Maybe "changing to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use into, because 'turning to' is normally used in a differently structured sentence, like the one below.

'people are slowly turning to fast food as a primary fuel' - this would be correct